# Why did my "not an answer" flag get declined?

Tags: discussion

I came across [a (now deleted) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58997665/leaflet-markers-not-shown/59000708#59000708) and someone posted this [ten word "answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59000708/3757232) that is just a guess. Why would a moderator decline my flagging this? Just a simple mistake?

---

Showing the answer here so everyone can see (not just 10K+):

> Your icon is invisible, something is probably wrong with the class

Comment: A guess is still an attempt to answer.

Comment: The real issue isn't that the answerer is making assumptions, but that they don't provide a solution

Comment: I also had a NAA flag declined recently where the answer was nevertheless deleted. Actually, I was half expecting it, after the event … the case in question was where a user had essentially just copied another answer: both were very short, but there was a big time-gap (months) between them. In hindsight, I think a custom flag would have been better, explaining the nature of the issue.

Answer (score 7):

An answer can be wrong, or a guess, while still being an attempted answer to the question.

In this case, an expert in CSS can make a great guess at why an icon is invisible, for instance in the case of a known CSS framework with known behaviours, possibly solving the problem. Whether said expert should close the question instead of answering is another debate, but they would still be answering.

Useful chart from [Tom](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391768/why-did-my-not-an-answer-flag-get-declined/391770?noredirect=1#comment742717_391770), freely formatted :)

- "actual gibberish" => VLQ flag
- "gravely insulting content" => "rude or abusive" flag
- NAA is for link-only answers, "thanks" or "I also have this problem" posts or questions posted as an answer.

Comment: "actual gibberish" => VLQ flag, "gravely insulting content" => "rude or abusive" flag and NAA is for link-only answers, "thanks" or "I also have this problem" posts or questions posted as an answer.

Comment: So why keep crappy answers that noone's going to find useful?

Comment: We shouldn’t and don’t, @JL2210. But you shouldn’t flag them as “not an answer” unless they actually qualify for that flag’s description. It is not a catch-all flag for low-quality answers. That’s what the downvote and delete buttons are for. (Community deletion requires privileges to mitigate misuse and ensure that voters are familiar with the site’s standards.) Community deletion also allows subject-matter experts to exercise judgment about what answers are “crappy”, decisions that moderators cannot make because they are not experts on all topics covered here.